# Using the for loop to pull data from two lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

On python I have two lists basicaly

```
xvales = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
yvales = [100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75]
sumation = 0
```

How can I use a for loop and pull corresponding values from each list to use in a formula.first iteration i=2 and j=100. second iteration i=4 and j=95. third iteration i=6 and j=90. I think you understand what I'm trying to do.
I did try to do this.

```
For i in xvales and j in yvales:    
    v = i **2 / ( j+1 )    
    sumation += v
```

Answer (score 2):

```
total = sum(i**2 / (j+1) for i,j in zip(xvalues, yvalues))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`

```
>>> zip(xvales, yvales)
[(2, 100), (4, 95), (6, 90), (8, 85), (10, 80), (12, 75)]
```

Then, loop on it, and sum it:

```
sumation = sum(i **2 / ( j+1 ) for i, j in zip(xvales, yvales))
```

### Edit

However, you probably want a float division, else this results in `2`:

```
sumation = sum(i **2 / float( j+1 ) for i, j in zip(xvales, yvales))
# 4.475365812518561
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**zip**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function to iterate over both at once.

Maintaining the rest of your structure:

```
for i, j in zip(xvales, yvales):
    v = i **2 / ( j+1 )    
    sumation += v
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it

```
xvales = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
yvales = [100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75]
summation = sum([i ** 2 / (j+1) for i,j in zip(xvales, yvales)])
```